# Leaving Audit information from Entity JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table that has audit information in the same table.

I want to create entity without the audit columns.

Is it possible in JPA.

e.g 
Person Table 
columns: name, address, (audit information)insertTime, (audit information)loggedUser

Can I create entity using only non audit information.

Please help

Comment: can't you simply not have fields for the `insertTime` or `loggedUser` columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, the answer is yes: You can create an JPA entity and don't need to map all columns of your database table in the entity class.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Handy already said, the answer is yes. This feature can also be used to tailoring database views to specific entities.

On the other hand you now can't let the table be automatically created (e.g. when using Hibernate by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`) and so have to manage your schema yourself (which is no bad thing).